# Why message box is blank after reading text from image?

Tags: c#, .net, image, c#-4.0, image-processing

i am converting image to text but it returns blank message box

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            Image image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\home\Documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication2\WindowsFormsApplication2\jack.jpg");

            // Convert Image to byte[]
            System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat format = ImageFormat.Jpeg;
            image.Save(ms, format);
            byte[] imageBytes = ms.ToArray();

            // Convert byte[] to Base64 String
            string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
            MessageBox.Show(base64String.ToString());
        }
```

i checked in debugger, the value assigned to base64 variable is:

```
/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABIAAD/4Q/qRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgAAwEaAAUAAAABAAAAMgEbAAUAAAABAAAAOgEoAAMAAAABAAIAAAAAAEIAAABIAAAAAQAAAEgAAAABAAYBAwADAAAAAQAGAAABGgAFAAAAAQAAAJABGwAFAAAAAQAAAJgBKAADAAAAAQACAAACAQAEAAAAAQAAAKACAgAEAAAAAQAAD0IAAAAAAAAASAAAAAEAAABIAAAAAf/Y/+AAEEpGSUYAAQEBAEgASAAA/9sAQwAGBAUGBQQGBgUGBwcGCAoQCgoJCQoUDg8MEBcUGBgXFBYWGh0lHxobIxwWFiAsICMmJykqKRkfLTAtKDAlKCko/9sAQwEHBwcKCAoTCgoTKBoWGigoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgo.......
```

Image:

[image]

Comment: Have you used any image-processing 3rd party dll to achieve this?

Comment: You can't display an image in a `MessageBox`.  Create a new form with an `ImageBox` control to display the image.

Comment: sir i am using these

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

Comment: @shf301 , OP is asking , `how to extract text shown in image` and display that text in `MessageBox`, Correct @John Nash?

Comment: @shf301 sir i am converting IMAGE TO TEXT so no need of that

Comment: @ArindamNayak yes sir, bilkul theek

Comment: @JohnNash - Ah I see.  You'll need to find an OCR (Optical Character Recognition) library to process the image.

Comment: You have to use some 3rd party DLL, to achieve this, may be this tutorial will be helpful - http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Read-Extract-Text-from-Image-OCR-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx, 1 more - http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/ocrnet/Extracting%20Text%20from%20Part%20of%20an%20Image

Comment: I think there is confusion as to whether you are trying to extract the jarek text from the image, or encode the image file into plain text.

Comment: @WhoIsRich i am trying to extract text from image

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to show 180,000 characters in a popup box.

Over a certain length, it will simply fail and show a blank box instead.

For example this should display:

```
MessageBox.Show(base64String.Substring(0, 1000));
```

If you need the full thing, use a TextBox or output to a file instead.

Comment: wow it worked but text is in unreadalbe format 381208309140712094912740921894912910ch23hcndvjbvjdsf vj dfbv9df8b 9dsbndfjbkdfvkjldf

Comment: Your code is just converting the image file. To extract text you need something that can recognise the patterns of written english. This is not included in .NET, there are [options if you use Windows 8](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Uses-the-OCR-Library-to-2a9f5bf4) or you need to download a library.  Search on Google for 'C# OCR'. OCR is Optical Character Recognition.

Answer (score 0):

thanks guys you helped a lot, and now i have this code, which works like a charm

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using MODI;
using System.IO;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Upload(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string filePath = Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/" + Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName));
        FileUpload1.SaveAs(filePath);
        string extractText = this.ExtractTextFromImage(filePath);
        lblText.Text = extractText.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />");
    }

    private string ExtractTextFromImage(string filePath)
    {
        Document modiDocument = new Document();
        modiDocument.Create(filePath);
        modiDocument.OCR(MiLANGUAGES.miLANG_ENGLISH);
        MODI.Image modiImage = (modiDocument.Images[0] as MODI.Image);
        string extractedText = modiImage.Layout.Text;
        modiDocument.Close();
        return extractedText;
    }

}
```